# SAS selecting top logit models by AIC

Tags: sas, regression, logistic-regression, model-comparison

I have a problem with SAS `proc logistic`.

I was using the following procedures when I had OLS regression and everything worked OK:

```
proc reg data = input_data outest = output_data;
model y = x1-x25 / selection = cp aic stop = 10;
run;
quit;
```

Here I wanted SAS to estimate all possible regressions using combinations of 25 regressors (`x1-x25`) including no more than 10 regressors in model.

Basically, I want to do the same thing (estimate all possible models having 25 regressors with no more than 10 included in a model and output top-models in a dataset with corresponding AIC) but with logistic regression.

I also know that I can use `selection = score` in `Proc Logistic`, but I'm not sure how to use `outest=` then and whether Score Chi-square is really a reliable alternative to cp and AIC in `proc reg`

So far, I know how to do stepwise/backward/forward logistic regressions, but these methods do not suit me well and btw they display in the output dataset only the top-1 model, while I want at least top-100.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: One more question: How can I ask SAS to estimate all possible models given the regressors and choose top ones by AUROC (are under ROC curve)?

Comment: Whether the score chi-square is a reliable alternative to Cp and AIC is a question for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Have you tried a macro that creates the variable combinations?